# Mongoose Threshold 2nd hand

Tags: wheels, quick-release

The front quick release lever of my Mongoose Threshold is missing or broken.

I don't know the year of the bike and do not know how to determine it. There is a sticker that says ATB4130, another one that says "All Terrain" and 32" size. The tires are 26"

Can I just buy a new skewer, or just replace lever? How do I know skewer size to buy or can I repair what I have?

Answer (score 3):

The quick release lever is standard and you should just be able to pick one up second hand or from your local bike shop.  Make sure you get the one for the front and not for the rear.

Comment: Embarrassingly I know nothing about the lever tighteners - never used one. The one I have on the front just has a empty whole where the lever is missing,. Can I just buy the lever itself or do I need to buy the whole Skewer? I found a serial # on the bottom of frame: PK6 w20377. Also I was wondering how old the bike is and is there a diagram of the end of the front forks where the wheel attaches - there is like a retaining hole also and I have not seen the complete skewer/retainer(if any) assembly? Also, anywhere on line I could purchase the correct part?

Comment: You probably have to buy the whole thing, but  a skewer is pretty cheap so don't even think about it. They are also universal, and change only from mountain to road (and there are some variations in for the back wheel). Measure the size of your hub and get something on eBay. Or if you don't want to bother just go to a shop and let them help you. Again, skewers are cheap so getting one on a store or on eBay should' be such a difference.